# How to use cast operator

Tags: java, typecast-operator

I'm currently working on a problem in my homework. The question is:

"Write a program that prompts the user to input an integer between 0 and 35. If the number is less than or equal to 9, the program should output the number; otherwise, it should output A for 10, B for 11, C for 12, ..., and Z for 35. (Hint: Use the cast operator, static_cast() for numbers >= 10."

I don't know how to use the cast operator and I need some guidance.

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Question_4 {
public static void main(String args[]){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int integer = 0;

    System.out.println("Enter a number between 0 - 35: ");
    integer = sc.nextInt();

    if(integer <= 9){
        System.out.println("Number entered is " + integer);
    }
    else{

        System.out.println(static_cast.class<char>('A' + (integer - 
                                                            10)););
    }
}//END Main
}
```

Comment: `static_cast` is part of C++, not Java. Are you sure that assignment was designed for Java?

Comment: Yes. That is in the question

Comment: I would suggest you talk to your teacher about changing the assignment for the next group of students. It's not really fair on anyone for them to suggest using `static_cast` in Java, when it doesn't *exist* in Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do it like this:

```
System.out.println((char)((byte)'A' + (integer - 10)) );
```

- `(byte)'A'` will give u byte representation of the 'A' char (97)
- `(char)` will cast the number back to the character

Comment: Oh I see. Thanks for the tip. I just finished it

Comment: You don't need the cast to `byte` though - `char` is implicitly convertible to `int` anyway. Just `(char) ('A' + integer - 10)` will work.